# Email a Google form with Include a form in email option using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to send a Google form with included in email option using an apps script

On observing the URL parameters closely I have found a **emailform** paramter

https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/1WdGrnquFdUoGF6Q5WoEZl_ys_hFr6WtWO1tZiROrp1Y/emailform

How do I send or get a pure HTML email version of the form using apps script

[image]

Comment: Please show what you tried

Comment: When I hit the URL, its doesnt open, This is a POST request. Also it has a token appended to it. Hence I have no idea what that token is. Without token it throws error and URL becomes invalid.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding the the embed code to the email?